# Getting dexPathList error on my device when running but fine on other devices? Already added multidex to gradle

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

I am getting a weird issue when I run my app on my device it crashes however when I run on other devices everything runs properly. Here is the crash logCat. It is crashing on my device as it is not finding the class.

```
11-30 09:21:06.096 27037-27037/za.co.applord.standard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: za.co.applord.standard, PID: 27037
                                                                        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject;
                                                                            at co.chatsdk.firebase.FirebaseEventHandler.<init>(FirebaseEventHandler.java:38)
                                                                            at co.chatsdk.firebase.FirebaseEventHandler.shared(FirebaseEventHandler.java:46)
                                                                            at co.chatsdk.firebase.FirebaseCoreHandler.<init>(FirebaseCoreHandler.java:56)
                                                                            at co.chatsdk.firebase.FirebaseNetworkAdapter.<init>(FirebaseNetworkAdapter.java:12)
                                                                            at co.chatsdk.firebase.FirebaseModule.activate(FirebaseModule.java:11)
                                                                            at za.co.applord.standard.presentation.AndroidApplication.initChat(AndroidApplication.java:61)
                                                                            at za.co.applord.standard.presentation.AndroidApplication.onCreate(AndroidApplication.java:24)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1035)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6029)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:218)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standardbank-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standardbank-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standardbank-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standardbank-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standard-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standard-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standard-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standard-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standard-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standardbank-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standard-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/za.co.applord.standard-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/za.co.applord.standard-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                            at co.chatsdk.firebase.FirebaseEventHandler.<init>(FirebaseEventHandler.java:38) 
                                                                            at co.chatsdk.firebase.FirebaseEventHandler.shared(FirebaseEventHandler.java:46) 
                                                                            at co.chatsdk.firebase.FirebaseCoreHandler.<init>(FirebaseCoreHandler.java:56) 
                                                                            at co.chatsdk.firebase.FirebaseNetworkAdapter.<init>(FirebaseNetworkAdapter.java:12) 
                                                                            at co.chatsdk.firebase.FirebaseModule.activate(FirebaseModule.java:11) 
                                                                            at za.co.applord.standard.presentation.AndroidApplication.initChat(AndroidApplication.java:61) 
                                                                            at za.co.applord.standard.presentation.AndroidApplication.onCreate(AndroidApplication.java:24) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1035) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6029) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject
                                                                            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                    ... 19 more
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I have cleaned the project and rebuilt the project, I have added multidex to my gradle, I have cleared the apps data and uninstalled on the device and all those things but still crashes only on my device.

Why is it not finding this class on my device only?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your device os version??

Comment: device os version is 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to disable instant run in android studio and turn off automatic restore of data when re-installing the project